Cannot connect to Apple Vision Pro with Xcode
I am following the official documentation on how to connect the device but the Apple Vision Pro doesn't show up in the devices list to begin the process.
Device and Mac are on the same Wi-Fi network
Network is confirmed compatible with Bonjour (Airdrop works fine, can connect the display to my mac, I even tried in the Apple Store on their wifi network with no luck).
Settings > General > Remote Devices is selected and "Ready to Pair" is showing
Device is not showing up in the list in the Devices and Simulators window in Xcode.


Just tried on Apple Vision Pro and Xcode many times. It doesn't work though.
Device: Apple M2 Ultra
xcode version 15.4

Doublecheck on the Vision Pro: Settings, Privacy and Security, scroll to very bottom, Security section, "Developer Mode: On". You might need to restart Xcode after doing this.
An aside: if you're doing any serious dev work on the Vision Pro, you'll almost certainly want the $300 Developer Strap, which speeds up putting builds on the device and interacting with them through the debugger. It will also improve Xcode/AVP pairing.
